# How to use global variable in specs using protractor and Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

i'm trying to reach a global variable after some its.
For example:

```
var date = 0;

it('must set a value', function(){
    date = 5;
});

it('must compare', function(){
     expect(date).toBe(5);
});
```

Comment: they should all have access to that date.  I assume date is a var inside of a describe function, right?  Do you have a fiddle where this is not working?

Comment: @ScottFanetti No, I just want to get the value (5) from the it function (must set a value) and compare in other it function (must compare)

Comment: So what actually happens when you use this code and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @paulotarcio, This happens because of Asynchronous mode of execution. That is most important feature of Java Script. Do like  - add a section params:{date:null} in conf.js file and assign value to it "browser.params.date=5" in first it and use in second it like "expect(browser.params.date).toBe(5);"

Answer (score 0):

The `it` blocks shouldn't depend on each other. First because the execution is asynchronous what will lead you to unexpected behaviors. And second because the units tests should be easy to ready and independent... so when one fails, you know what actually failed (i.e. you don't need to look into other unit blocks)

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with your code but it seems to me that what you want is something like the following code:

```
describe('MyTestSpec', function () {

    var date = 0;

    beforeEach(function () {
        //Using beforeEach will actually assume that date will be set to 5
        //before the execution of your it-block.
        date = 5;
    });

    it('check if date is 5', function () {
        expect(date).toBe(5);     
    });
});
```